# Implementing Operator Overloading with Logarithms in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, logarithm

I'm having some issues with implementing a logarithm class with operator overloading in C++.

My first goal is how I would implement the `changeBase` method, I've been having a tough time wrapping my head around it.

I have tried to understand the math behind changing the base of a logarithm, but i haven't been able to. Can someone please explain it to me?

My second goal is to be able to perform an operation where the left operand is a `double` and the right operand is a logarithm object.

Here's a snippet of my log class:

```
// coefficient: double
// base: unsigned int
// result: double
class _log {

 double coefficient, result;
 unsigned int base;

public:

 _log() {
  base = 10;
  coefficient = 0.0;
  result = 0.0;
 }
 _log operator+ ( const double b ) const;
 _log operator* ( const double b ) const;
 _log operator- ( const double b ) const;
 _log operator/ ( const double b ) const;
 _log operator<< ( const _log &b );

 double getValue() const;

 bool changeBase( unsigned int base );
};
```

**You guys are awesome, thank you for your time.**

Comment: Could you be more specific about the difficulty you are having  implementing the change of base?

Comment: @James, sorry. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What are `coefficient` and `number`? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm: are the common names `characteristic` and `mantissa`?

Comment: The result of what? I only see it getting randomized. Results should be returned from functions, never persistently stored in such a structure.

Comment: Also, where is the fractional part of the logarithm? If you wanted to represent the number 3 in a base besides 3, how would you do it?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, I have no clue how I'm going to do this. That's why I asked here.

Comment: I appreciate the accepted answer, but it's also OK to wait for more suggestions, try and see if mine work, implement the next step and update with more questions, etc…

Comment: @Potatoswatter, most definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things

1. Using an _ in the front of your class is a Very Bad Idea (tm). From the c++ standard:

> **17.4.3.2.1 Global names [lib.global.names]**
>   Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the
>   implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with
>     an underscore followed by an uppercase
>     letter (2.11) is reserved to the
>     implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the
>     implementation for use as a name in
>     the global namespace.<sup>165</sup>
>
> 165) Such names are also reserved in namespace ::std (17.4.3.1).

2. I'm guessing that you used _log instead of log due to the clash with log() in cmath. It is a Very Bad Idea to keep your own classes in the standard namespace for this very reason. Maybe the next version of the standard will provide a _log or Logarithm class? 
   Wrap your own class in `namespace somename {}` and reference it by using `somename::Logarithm()`
3. As others have mentioned already You need to declare your operator overloading as friend. Instead of what you have

   `log operator+ ( const double b ) const;`

   change it to

   ```
   friend log operator+(const double d, const log& l);
   ```

   and define the function in the namespace scope.
4. Here is the math for the change of base formula

   [image: Change of base formula]
5. Coefficient in math means the part that is being multiplied by the log. So if you had 
   A log_b(x) = y

   A is the coefficient, B is the base, and Y is the result (or some other names)

Answer (score 5):

> My second goal is to be able to perform an operation where the left operand is a double and the right operand is a logarithm object.

To do this, you need to declare the operator as a non-member function at namespace scope (i.e., not in the definition of `_log`), e.g.,

```
_log operator+(const double a, const _log& b);
```

If you need access to the private members of `_log`, you can declare it as a friend inside the definition of `_log`:

```
friend _log operator+(const double a, const _log& b);
```

Note that names starting with an underscore (e.g., `_log`) are reserved to the implementation in the global namespace; if the underscore is followed by a capital letter or another underscore, it is reserved everywhere.  It would be a good idea to choose a different class name.

Comment: In the non member operator case, it is nice to try to avoid saying friend. Since you already have a member addition operator, implementing the other direction as a non friend non member function in terms of that is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

1. Don't name with a leading underscore. Such identifiers are radioactive in C and C++.
2. Define operations between logarithms before operations with floats.
3. Combine #2 with James' suggestion:

   ```
   friend logarithm operator+( const logarithm &l, const logarithm &r );
   ```
4. Define a conversion constructor to generate a `logarithm` from a float:

   ```
   logarithm::logarithm( double f );
   ```

   Now C++ will convert the `double` to a `logarithm` in either `1.0 + my_log` or `my_log + 1.0`.
5. Implement [natural logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) in your class. Don't bother with `base`.
6. Define base conversion in terms of a function:

   ```
   double alternate_base( double base ) const;
   ```

   Base conversion is simply dividing the `logarithm` by the natural log of the alternate base. It is probably most convenient to return the integer and fractional parts together in a single `double`.